# How to use Signature or User ID to get user's information?

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm a beginner at Wikimedia, and I'm using Wiki API to finish my project. My dataset looks like this:

```
rev_id | comment | timestamp | page_id | page_title | user_id | user_text
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
352194497 | Welcome to Wikipedia | 2010-03-26T18:16:48Z | 26709696 | 116.197.206.138 | 8356162 | Mlpearc
```

I'm trying to find some user information of these comment posters. However, I find the "user_text" here is not the user name but the signature. If I use the official API demos `get_users.py` to get the information, it turns out the error because some signature have space in it, but usernames are all single word. Like in the code below, I can get the information of Catrope and Bob using `Catrope|Bob`. But it doesn't work if I use `Catrope|Tide rolls`, if Tide rolls is the signature.

```
import requests

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

PARAMS = {
    "action": "query",
    "format": "json",
    "list": "users",
    "ususers": "Catrope|Tide rolls",
    "usprop": "blockinfo|groups|editcount|registration|emailable|gender"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
DATA = R.json()

USERS = DATA["query"]["users"]

for u in USERS:
    print(str(u["name"]) + " has " + str(u["editcount"]) + " edits.")
```

So my question is, is there any way that we can get user information through the signature using API? And since we also have page_id and user_id here, will this information be helpful? Thank you so much in advance!

Updated: I used `Bob Ben` here as a fake ID. Now it is replaced by a real one. Problems solved by using _ to replace space.(Thanks for the reminder from AXO.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not mentioned the error and traceback that you're getting. The code sample should work fine as long as the username exists, even if the username has a space in it.

But [user account "Bob Ben" is not registered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Bob_Ben). In such cases the API replies with `{'name': 'Bob Ben', 'missing': ''}`.

So you're code could be:

```
for u in USERS:
    if 'missing' not in u:
        print(u["name"] + " has " + str(u["editcount"]) + " edits.")
    else:
        print(u["name"], "is not registered.")
```

BTW, if for some reason you prefer not to use space, you may use `_` (underscore) instead. [A blank space is equivalent with an underscore.](https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Help:Page_name&oldid=19312481#Spaces_vs._underscores)

Regarding "user information", I'm not sure what kind of information you're looking for. According to [API:Users](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Users) one may get `blockinfo|groups|groupmemberships|implicitgroups|rights|editcount|registration|emailable|gender|centralids|cancreate` using the `usprop` parameter. But if some other information, for example the information on the user page, is to be fetched, then you'll perhaps need to use one of the methods mentioned in [API:Get the contents of a page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page) to get the contents of the user page and then write a program to look for the information you need.

Comment: Hi AXO! Thank you so much for your reply. Yes, Bob Ben is a "fake" name I used for explanation. In case it causes confusion, I have updated a real user name. Thank you again!

Comment: By the way, may I ask is there any other properties that I can use to get user information? Like here we already have edit count and registration. Do you know where I can find the function for other usages? Like get the self-introduction on the user page? Thank you!

Comment: Great! That's all I'm looking for. Thanks a lot, AXO!